# Getting the first child element is throwing an error in typescript

Tags: html, typescript

I am trying to fetch the first child element of each list item in a typescript file, but typescript always throws error:
**Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLUListElement': compact, type, accessKey, accessKeyLabel, and 109 more.** If I neglect this warning and run the HTML file, it works and logs the first first HTML child element, but I need to find a solution to this error to keep a clean code. How can I please remove this error?

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li')

li.forEach((listItem: HTMLLIElement)=> {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', (): void => {
  err>  const *liChild*: HTMLUListElement = listItem.firstElementChild
                  ^ error location
        console.log(liChild)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `firstElementChild` will be a `<ul>`. It could be any other element, or no element at all (`null`). So trying to assign this to a `HTMLUListElement` results in a type error.

If you don't actually care that it's specifically a ul, then either use a type that matches:

```
listItem.addEventListener("click", (): void => {
  const child: Element | null = listItem.firstElementChild;
})
```

Or leave off the type and typescript will give it that same type automatically

```
listItem.addEventListener("click", (): void => {
  const child = listItem.firstElementChild;
})
```

If you need to make sure you're dealing with a `<ul>`, then you'll need to write code to check for that:

```
listItem.addEventListener("click", (): void => {
  const child = listItem.firstElementChild;
  if (child && child instanceof HTMLUListElement) {
    const ul: HTMLUListElement = child;
    console.log(ul);
  }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgSxgXhgExMArgWwKZhQB0AjlngE4CeAynnHsFCBQIJxwAUARItwJQBuAFDDERAGYsAogENgAC06dE0AJJQ8OAFwwAEgBUAsgBkTa6Q3yF%20KAHwwA3sJjwE6zTiKy0aaQDcCKBN3TTBKHmBEYABrbgAaGE5%20XX8QBDR7JxdXGFBIWEUEOEzUVSgNLUkECmhLLSCAYQVitBFcmAQJJKKSmAAyfryWvoQC2TBgPBBuw1MAVRC6qyDbZw7XfOgYLDhdOZNF0PrrWFRetpyOrZAGIjgQAHNOXaErmABfHI%203n8EgA)